# What is the best way to embed a user's tweets and mentions into a website?

Tags: twitter, tweets

I need to embed a specific user's recent tweets onto the home page of a website. The website is built in ASP.NET.

I've looked at the Twitter REST API and have tried using the `user_timeline`. It works but does not include *mentions* for the user. I want to include *mentions* but the only way to do it seems to be by using APIs that require authentication. I would prefer not to use authentication as it seems it would start to make things more complicated. I also do not want to get the current user to authenticate.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`GET search`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search) API instead. Search for statuses containing the user's @username, but in this case it will not return mentions from private/locked accounts since there's no authentication.

For example, if you want to search mentions for @stackexchange, call this.

```
GET http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=@stackexchange
```

Comment: Ah cool. I think that'll do it. Then I can combine it with the `user_timeline` results.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a search for @username using the REST Search api.  There's a good chance that would work :)